# Powershell: show progress for a 3 days script

Tags: powershell, progress

I wrote a simple script that calls a test that takes about 3 days. I redirect the test's output to a log file, so when running the script there's nothing on the screen to indicate progress. It's very simple:

```
CD C:\Test
test.exe > log.txt
```

I can check the log file every once in a while sure, but if the machine freezes (which happens) I wouldn't notice right away.

So, I need an idea of a nice way to show progress. Outputting a dot every now and then is not nice I think, since it takes 3 days! Any other idea? As a beginner in PowerShell, an implementation for a given idea would also be nice.

Much appreciated,
Yotam

Comment: Can you post any code?

Comment: Done, like I said very simple :)

Comment: `Tee-Object` might be useful, but it depends a lot on how exactly you are writing/redirecting the output. Another option is `Get-Content` with the `-Wait` flag.

Comment: Assuming TEST.EXE generates regular output, you could monitor the 'LastWriteTime' of LOG.TXT. If it falls back more than, say, 10 minutes, then send an alert email.